# Slide a panel from the side using Storyboard

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm, transition

I have 3 grids. `canvas`, `main` and `sidebar`

```
<Grid x:Name="canvas">
    <Grid x:Name="main"/>
    <Grid x:Name="sidebar"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to create an animation in my WPF MVVM application in which when I click a certain button, the `main` panel should move to the left (outside of the `canvas`) and `sidebar` should take its place with the same animation. Basically, it should look like the sidebar is pushing the `main` outside of the `canvas`. And when I click another button the reverse of the exact animation should run. (like the `main` is pushing `sidebar` outside of the `canvas`.

I tried to create a `Style` and add some `Trigger`s on `Visibility` property of the `Grid`s. I was somewhat successful in half of the animation but couldn't get it to reverse and animation both panels at the same time.

```
    <Style TargetType="Grid"  x:Key="VisibleAnimation">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                         From="300" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Please note that I'm looking for an MVVM solution so no code behind should be involved if possible.

Comment: MVVM is not about eliminating view-related code such as animations from the views...this question has nothing to do with MVVM. The approach would be exactly the same regardless of whether you follow the MVVM pattern or not.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now, what's the approach?